# Clojure not nil check

Tags: clojure

In Clojure `nil?` checks for nil. How does one check for not nil?

I want to do the Clojure equivalent of the following Java code:

```
if (value1==null && value2!=null) {
}
```

**Follow-up:** I was hoping for a not nil check instead of wrapping it with `not`. `if` has a `if-not` counterpart. Is there such a counterpart for `nil?`?

Comment: You want a not-nil? Easily done: `(def not-nil? (comp not nil?))`

Comment: You should accept [liwp's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24043448/405550). A lot of people arriving here from Google won't scroll past the accepted answer to find out that the opposite of `nil?` is `some?`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Another way to define `not-nil?` would be using the `complement` function, which just inverts the truthyness of a boolean function:

```
(def not-nil? (complement nil?))
```

If you have several values to check then use `not-any?`:

```
user> (not-any? nil? [true 1 '()])
true
user> (not-any? nil? [true 1 nil])
false
```

Comment: @mikera's answer should be selected as the correct answer.

Answer (score 110):

After Clojure 1.6 you can use `some?`:

```
(some? :foo) => true
(some? nil) => false
```

This is useful, eg, as a predicate:

```
(filter some? [1 nil 2]) => (1 2)
```

Comment: Possible gotcha:  `(filter some? [1 nil false 2]) => (1 false 2)`

Comment: @madstap How so? The question asks how to check for values that are not `nil`, and none of `(1 false 2)` are `nil`.

Comment: Yeah, actually you're right... Dunno why I was surprised ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: You were surprised because both `nil` and `false` are considered falsy in some clojure forms (like `if`). So I still think its a gotcha :)

Answer (score 19):

If you are not interested in distinguishing `false` from `nil`, you can just use the value as the condition:

```
(if value1
   "value1 is neither nil nor false"
   "value1 is nil or false")
```

Answer (score 18):

In Clojure, **nil counts as false for the purposes of conditional expressions**.

As a result `(not x)` works actually works exactly the same as as `(nil? x)` in most cases (with the exception of boolean false). e.g.

```
(not "foostring")
=> false

(not nil)
=> true

(not false)  ;; false is the only non-nil value that will return true
=> true
```

So to answer your original question  you can just do:

```
(if (and value1 (not value2)) 
   ... 
   ...)
```

Comment: Isn't this answer exactly the opposite? (not "foostring") => false is opposite what I would expect from (not-nil? "foostring") also I would expect (not-nil? nil) to return false not true.

Answer (score 7):

condition: `(and (nil? value1) (not (nil? value2)))`

if-condition: `(if (and (nil? value1) (not (nil? value2))) 'something)`

EDIT:
Charles Duffy provides correct custom definition for `not-nil?`:

> You want a not-nil? Easily done: `(def not-nil? (comp not nil?))`

Answer (score 6):

If you want your test to return `true` when given `false`, then you need one of the other answers here.  But if you just want to test that returns a truthy value whenever it's passed something other than `nil` or `false`, you can use `identity`.  For example, to strip `nil`s (or `false`s) from a sequence:

```
(filter identity [1 2 nil 3 nil 4 false 5 6])
=> (1 2 3 4 5 6)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try  [when-not](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/when-not) :

```
user> (when-not nil (println "hello world"))
=>hello world
=>nil

user> (when-not false (println "hello world"))
=>hello world
=>nil

user> (when-not true (println "hello world"))
=>nil


user> (def value1 nil)
user> (def value2 "somevalue")
user> (when-not value1 (if value2 (println "hello world")))
=>hello world
=>nil

user> (when-not value2 (if value1 (println "hello world")))
=>nil
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a `not-nil?` function, then I'd suggest just defining it as follows:

```
(defn not-nil? 
  (^boolean [x]
    (not (nil? x)))
```

Having said that it is worth comparing the usage of this to the obvious alternative:

```
(not (nil? x))
(not-nil? x)
```

I'm not sure that introducing an extra non-standard function is worth it for saving two characters / one level of nesting. It would make sense though if you wanted to use it in higher order functions etc.

Answer (score 1):

One more option:

```
(def not-nil? #(not= nil %))
```